# Form Validation With Regex

Tags: javascript, php, regex

I've written a function to validate if a password is valid. The only problem I'm having is figuring out why this pattern that I've written in JavaScript isn't evaluating to true when tested with a password such as: 'SteveRogers#256'. Is this an issue with the way I've declared the regex pattern?

**PHP**

```
function check_password($pass_word)
{
    $pattern = "#.*^(?=.{8,15})(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*\W).*$#";

    return (preg_match($pattern, $pass_word));
}
```

**JavaScript**

```
function check_password(pass_word) {
    var pattern = new RegExp("#.*^(?=.{8,15})(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*\W).*$#");

    return pattern.test(pass_word);
}
```

Comment: javascript doesn't use pattern delimiters in the pattern string like php does. You need to remove the `#` from the js one.

Comment: i hate sites that dictate i must use there (almost always) bad idea for what a safe password is.

Comment: @Dagon Haha, right? I just needed something for now. I'll harden up the pattern soon.

Comment: even better, remove it altogether.

Comment: @Dagon What would you suggest?

Comment: not validating the password at all

Comment: i don't mind sites who show a suggested "strength" meter or message of some sorts but enforcing a pattern is annoying and also helps out crackers narrow down possibilities

Comment: many "strength" meter's are garbage, and accept terrible passwords as "strong", how would it know if a user used his address as the password -long with number and letters but still a terrible idea

Comment: well the point is to not enforce a pattern. If I were to write a "strength" meter it would evaluate whether the user is trying to enter in the same thing like their address or username and tell them it's stupid.  But again, the point is to not enforce the pattern

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove regex delimiters in Javascript as `new RegExp` takes a String in the constructor. Correct Javascript code should be:

```
var pattern = new RegExp("^(?=.*?[a-z])(?=.*?[A-Z])(?=.*?[0-9])(?=.*?\\W).{8,15}$");
```

Comment: Appreciate the feedback!

Comment: +1 But note that there is a more efficient expression that does not require the dot star: `/^(?=[^a-z]*[a-z])(?=[^A-Z]*[A-Z])(?=[^0-9]*[0-9])(?=\w*\W).{8,15}$/`

Comment: @ridgerunner: Thanks, yes I agree with your suggestion. I myself have used these lookaheads that way in the past.

Comment: @ridgerunner: You may find this discussion interesting: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20194698/548225