# %etd(msg01) regular expression?

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to write a regular expression for String like `%etd(msg01)`.

```
String string = "My name is %etd(msg01) and %etd(msg02)";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("%etd(.+)");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);

while(matcher.find()) {
   System.out.println(matcher.group());
}
```

It prints `%etd(msg01) and %etd(msg02)`. However, I want it to print `%etd(msg01)` `%etd(msg02)` separately. I mean I am looking for non-greedy match.

How should the regular expression be changed to make it non greedy in this situation?

Comment: If you know you're looking for a non-greedy match, why haven't you written a regular expression that uses one?

Comment: @user1661951 Did you try given solutions?

Answer (score 2):

You should use this regex:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("%etd\\([^)]+\\)");
```

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik: I'm a bit surprized that you made this suggestion. IMO negation in regex is considered better and more efficient than using `.*?` OR `.+?`

Comment: I hardly believe the difference in efficiency will ever become evident here, and simplicity itself is a feature. Apply best practices where they make sense.

Comment: ...or, if you are proposing a non-obvious solution, include argumentation *why* OP should use your version. "considered better" is not much of an argument, and "considered efficient" doesn't even make sense. It either *is* or *isn't* more efficient.

Comment: What is non-obvious for one person can be obvious for other person.

Comment: By that argument you shouldn't even have written the answer because it is obvious to *some* people. Not to OP, for one.

Comment: No, I am not a mind reader; however that has zero relevance to this discussion. You had no basis to assume that it is obvious to OP (or the general reader) *why* he should use your version of the regex.

Comment: I didn't assume anything. I provided a fairly simple answer to a simple problem. Read the comments above where you started with `...or, if you are proposing a non-obvious solution` Hope it is obvious to you  now.

Comment: @Marko Topolnik - Please go read: [Mastering Regular Expressions (3rd Edition)](http://www.amazon.com/Mastering-Regular-Expressions-Jeffrey-Friedl/dp/0596528124). The expression: `/\([^()]*\)/` is certainly more efficient than `/\(.*?\)/` in every language except possibly Perl (whose regex engine is highly optimized for the lazy dot star expression). The expression `.*?` must stop and backtrack once at every character position as it "bumps-along", whereas the greedy quantifier applied to the negated character class expression can consume the entire chunk in a single step, with no backtracking.

Comment: @ridgerunner Bravo, that is exactly what anubhava had to put into his answer for the answer to make any sense at all. And as for me, I still argue that such micro-optimization is overkill most of the time; you would first need to have a performance issue to go bothering with this and other fine points of regex.

Comment: @ridgerunner: Many thanks for looking at this thread and supporting my point of efficient regex. Hope it settles the matter.

Comment: @ridgerunner For the record, instead of waving textbook quotes around, I benchmarked it. For this string `"My name is %etd(msg01aosnetuhasnoetuhasnoetuhsanoetuhansoteuhassnthnoetuh) saonteuhsnt"` the execution time is around one microsecond. The reluctant version gives 0.9 ops/µs and the negative gives 1.38 ops/µs---an advantage if measly 50% for the worst case.

Answer (score 1):

Please place a question mark after .* or .+ to make it nongreedy. This should work for you...

`Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("%etd\\(.+?\\)");`

Double slashes are also necessary in front of open and close parenthesis because they carry a special meaning in regular expression.

Another way of using is as below if you are sure that your names doesn't contain an open paranthesis after the first one.

`Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("%etd\\([^(]+\\)");`